# python shutil.copyfile: retrieve an overwritten copy

Tags: python, shutil

I have accidentally overwritten my file using shutil.copyfile; is there any way to retrieve a previous copy? (I did not use anything like git/time machine/etc.)
thanks!

Comment: Unless your file system / operating system stores a (temp) copy somewhere, no, there's probably not.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

> shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
>
> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file
> named src to a file named dst. dst must be the complete target file
> name; look at shutil.copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory
> path. If src and dst are the same files, Error is raised. The
> destination location must be writable; otherwise, an IOError exception
> will be raised. **If dst already exists, it will be replaced**. Special
> files such as character or block devices and pipes cannot be copied
> with this function. src and dst are path names given as strings.

If the files were not the same then you have replaced it without a safe-copy.

Comment: Thanks. I assume there is no way to retrieve it then. :(

Answer (score 0):

shutil.copyfile requires a source and a destination file.  According to the standard library documentation,

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html

> If src and dst specify the same file, SameFileError is raised.

So, it should not be overwritten, you should have 2 files.

Comment: no, they were not the same. One of the files was empty.

Comment: @yuliagrishina for future reference it will be more useful to be explicit on the situation.  how many files there are, which one you think was overwritten, maybe a code snippet.  If you have ovewritten the dst file, then you are out of luck.  I was under the assumption that it was the src file you were concerned about.